# How does Pagination work in YouTube API (apiclient.discovery)?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I'm pretty new to working with the YouTube API and I've looking for a way to collect a bunch of channel data. However, the API is limited to 50 results per request. To get more results it allows you to use pagination. When I query a result I get the following token:

```
'nextPageToken': 'CDIQAA'
```

This token can be used to query the next set of results. So, it allows me to go to page 2 and get new results there. However, this token value changes when I get to page 2. This has lead to the following question:

**How do I use the page token/pagination to get all the results possible?**

I'm aware that this query will give a lot of results and that I need to filter more ;)

```
from apiclient.discovery import build


api_key = "My_key"

youtube = build('youtube','v3',developerKey = api_key)
print(type(youtube))

request = youtube.search().list(
    q='Fishing',
    part='snippet',
    type='channel',
    maxResults=50
)
print(type(request))
res = request.execute()
print(res)

for item in res['items']:
    print(item['snippet']['title'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the data from `youtube.search().list(q = 'A query', part = 'id,snippet', type = 'video', maxResults = 50, relevanceLanguage = 'en', videoDuration = 'long')` using `pageToken`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build


api_key = "My_key"

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

data = []
pageToken = ""
while True:
    res = youtube.search().list(
        q='Fishing',
        part='snippet',
        type='channel',
        maxResults=50,
        pageToken=pageToken if pageToken != "" else ""
    ).execute()
    v = res.get('items', [])
    if v:
        data.extend(v)
    pageToken = res.get('nextPageToken')
    if not pageToken:
        break

# print(len(data)) # You can check the number of retrieved data.

for item in data:
    print(item['snippet']['title'])
```

#### Reference:

- [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Comment: That's it! I just retrieved over 500 channels based on your query!
If I'm correct, it checks whether there is a pageToken. If there is, it goes to the next page. Why do we use .extend for the list and not .append? :)

Comment: @Jorginton Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Why do we use .extend for the list and not .append?`, the value of `res.get('items', [])` is like `[,,,]`. In this script, the retrieved value is put in a 1-dimensional array. So I used `extend`. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter called pageToken that you can send along with your request. There is a little bit about this in the documentation [implementation/pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) but not a lot.

```
request = youtube.search().list(
    q='Fishing',
    part='snippet',
    type='channel',
    pageToken='tokenFromPrevousCall',
    maxResults=50
)
```

The trick will be adding this to a loop and doing it recursively.  It seams the client library may have something that can help [docs/pagination](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/pagination.html)

```
request = youtube.search().list(
   q = 'A query',
   part = 'id,snippet',
   type = 'video',
   maxResults = 50,
   relevanceLanguage = 'en',
   videoDuration = 'long'
)

while request:
   response = request.execute()

for item in response['items']:
   ...

   request = youtube.search().list_next(
      request, response)  // Get next set of results
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've read and seen the documentation. However, and this may sound stupid, but I don't understand it (yet). How do I get the token from the previous call? And also, how would I include this in the example above.

You don't have to completely write it out for me but I'm struggling to get a grasp on this concept! :)

Comment: Check the link from the client library  request = youtube.search().list_next(
      request, response) should do it all for you.

Comment: Ah, your edit clear up a lot of confusion. But I noticed that you don't use the ```pagetoken``` in your script. Also, when running it, it burns all my daily quota:

After creating a new API key on another Google account, I get the following:
```The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>."```

Comment: The thing is im not a python developer i just go that code from the sample :).     Pagination will eat quota you charged for each request you make even for the next page.

Comment: No worries, you helped me to understand the concept! :)